# Planning for a large Yii2 application

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture, yii2

I am thinking about how to build a large application for a client in Yii2. My experience comes from several smaller Yii2 projects.

What are some major decisions that have to be made during the first steps which cannot be changed easily later on and what are typical Yii2 solution patterns for that?

Here are some features I'm thinking of:

**User Administration**

A jump start is the extension Yii2-user or Yii2-usario. Gives user management, user login, password reset features and the like.

**Multi-tenancy**

To manage multiple clients in one database, it is recommended to add the client id to every table and use Yii2 behaviors to add this table field to every database query.

**Optional / complex features**

Yii2 provides "modules" for code separation. Yii2 modules can have components, models, views, controllers,... and are perfect for delivering independent features at a later stage. Or to separate features from the core application.

Are there similar Yii2 patterns to know about from the start of the project in order to avoid major refactoring during the project?

Comment: Is there a good solution for integrated oniine help oder manuals? Preferably help where a user can make comments on his/her own?

Answer (score 2):

An important patter  available in Yii2 is for me the  **RBAC** (authorization acces by roles) ..

If the application is large remember you could need  **Internazionalization** for date, currency and formate  and multilangue

**Audit**  for check who access  to what  (there are good extension for this too)

Comment: Can you help me !! how to do audit in yii2

Comment: i have used  this and is good for my need  https://github.com/bedezign/yii2-audit

Comment: I also using same extension but i am new bie for this framework so i can not getting  how to use this

Comment: i have done what in https://bedezign.github.io/yii2-audit/docs/installation/  and work

Comment: Internationalization is a good topic:I used an intermediate language as first language (e.g. "button-submit") an then translate this into english ('Submit") and other languages. Why is this not the default language in Yii2? Any reason why this is not recommended?

Comment: @scaisEdge I have done this but i don't how to insert trailing and other audit logs in DB

Comment: @MayankVadiya  you should post a specific question about your topic ..eg Yii2 Audit ..

Comment: @WeSee  Because the english is the most use/common  language so this is used  as dafualt  ..but the logic is the same as what you are trying to do ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860644/audit-module-cannot-be-loaded-using-yii2-audit @scaisEdge

Comment: Yii2's RBAC is the biggest issue here. It assumes all tenants will use an identical graph, which is often not the case. The only way around that is to write your own multi-tenant implementation or RBAC.

Answer (score 1):

in yii2, you can run multiple applications from one codebase. yii2's advanced template gives you great starting point, but you might have more than one "frontend" application. this will help you **share or split** configurations (including databases) for your frontends. so you can reuse common modules in your applicaions, plus have the freedom to do something completely different.

maybe this is out of scope, but for implementing multi-tenancy i did limit access to data-rows to group members only via behaviour.
a where-clause is auto-applied to all selects, so you the client can only return those rows he owns. in your code you can now do select's and join's without having to think about ownership.

**ActiveRecord.php**

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Url;

class ActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'group' => [
                'class'     => \x1\data\behaviors\GroupBehavior::className(),
                'map'       => ['gid' => 'group_id'],
                'className' => \common\models\Group::className(),
            ],
        ];
    }


    public static function checkAccess() {
        if (!Yii::$app instanceof \yii\console\Application) {
            $user     = Yii::$app->get('user', false);
            $identity = ($user) ? $user->getIdentity() : null;

            if (empty($identity)) {
                if (!empty($user->loginUrl))
                    return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect($user->loginUrl);
                else
                    throw new \yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException;
            }
        }
    }


    //
    //  select only rows within the user's group,
    //  except for console app
    //
    public static function find() {
        self::checkAccess();
        return (new ActiveQuery(get_called_class()))->current();
    }

}

?>
```

**GroupBehaviour.php**

```
<?php
namespace x1\data\behaviors;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\db\BaseActiveRecord;

/*

class myModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'group' => [
                'class'     => \x1\data\behaviors\GroupBehavior::className(),
                'map'       => ['gid' => 'group_id'],
                'className' => \common\models\Group::className(),
            ],
        ];
    }

}

 */
class GroupBehavior extends \yii\behaviors\AttributeBehavior
{
    public $map       = ['gid' => 'group_id'];
    public $className = null;
    public $value;


    public function getGroup() {
        return $this->owner->hasOne($this->className, $this->map);
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        if ($this->className == null) {
            throw new \yii\base\InvalidConfigException("'className' must be set");
        }

        if (!is_array($this->map)) {
            throw new \yii\base\InvalidConfigException("'map' must be an array; e.g.: ['gid' => 'group_id']");
        } else {
            if (!count($this->map) > 0) {
                throw new \yii\base\InvalidConfigException("'map' must contain the mapping group => local; e.g.: ['gid' => 'group_id']");
            }
        }

        if (!Yii::$app instanceof \yii\console\Application) {
            if (empty($this->attributes)) {
                $this->attributes = [
                    BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => array_values($this->map)[0],
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates the value of the user.
     * The return result of this method will be assigned to the current attribute(s).
     * @param Event $event
     * @return mixed the value of the user.
     */
    protected function getValue($event)
    {
        if ($this->value === null) {
            $user  = Yii::$app->get('user', false);
            $group = array_keys($this->map)[0];
            return ($user && !$user->isGuest) ? $user->identity->group->$group : null;
        } else {
            return call_user_func($this->value, $event);
        }
    }

}
```

**ActiveQuery.php**

```
<?php
namespace common\models;
use Yii;

class ActiveQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery
{
    private $_alias = null;

    private function getAlias() {

        if ($this->_alias === null) {

            if (empty($this->from)) {
                $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
                $tableName  = $modelClass::tableName();
            } else {
                foreach ($this->from as $alias => $tableName) {
                    if (is_string($alias)) {
                        $this->_alias = $alias;
                        return $this->_alias;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (preg_match('/^(.*?)\s+({{\w+}}|\w+)$/', $tableName, $matches)) {
                $this->_alias = $matches[2];
            } else {
                $this->_alias = $tableName;
            }

        }
        return $this->_alias;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        $alias = $this->getAlias();

        if (!Yii::$app instanceof \yii\console\Application)
            $this->andWhere(['IN', sprintf('COALESCE(%s.group_id,0)', $alias), [0, Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id]]);

        return $this;
    }


    public function rawSql() {
        return $this->prepare(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. But wow, that's a lot of code. Why not just using one little behavior in ActiveRecord that checks if the record belongs to the tentant of the user?

Comment: i couldn't find a simpler solution - feedback welcome. 
1. extend ActiveQuery to auto add a filter per client.
2. register this ActiveQuery in ActiveRecord.

GroupBehaviour might not be necessary.