# Declaration of bedezign\yii2\audit\components\panels\DataStoragePanelTrait::getUrl() using yii2-audit

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, audit-trail, audit-tables

I am using [yii2-audit](https://bedezign.github.io/yii2-audit/docs/installation/) extension for audit logs, I followed all steps of installation and also migrate all tables.
But when I update table value then it will return error like **Audit module cannot be loaded**.

I have place `behaviors()` in my `model`.

**My Model**

```
<?php
namespace frontend\models;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use bedezign\yii2\models\AuditTrail;
use bedezign\yii2\audit\models\AuditEntry;
use bedezign\yii2\Audit;
class StudentForm extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'AuditTrailBehavior' => [
                'class' => 'bedezign\yii2\audit\AuditTrailBehavior',
                // Array with fields to save. You don't need to configure both `allowed` and `ignored`
                'allowed' => ['firstname','lastname','email','phone'],
                'active' => true,
                // Date format to use in stamp - set to "Y-m-d H:i:s" for datetime or "U" for timestamp
                'dateFormat' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
            ]
        ];
    }
```

My question is

1. Why I am getting error like **Audit module cannot be loaded** ?
2. Why any error or other logs are not storing into `audit` tables ?

I have added `audit` in `main.php`

```
'modules' => [
        'audit' => 'bedezign\yii2\audit\Audit',
    ],
```

After added I am getting error like below image.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us error? Not just text.

Comment: `in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii_basic\demo\vendor\bedezign\yii2-audit\src\AuditTrailBehavior.php`

Comment: It's not an error. Provide a screen of full error message.

Comment: @Yupik I have edited my question plz review it

Comment: Did you add `'audit' => 'bedezign\yii2\audit\Audit',` in your `main.php`?

Comment: No, But I have added recently its giving error like `Declaration of bedezign\yii2\audit\panels\RequestPanel::getUrl() should be compatible with yii\debug\Panel::getUrl($additionalParams = NULL)`

Comment: What version of Yii2 youre using?

Comment: its yii2 advanced

Comment: Yes, but which version? 2.0.12?

Comment: i am using 2.0.6

Comment: So that's the problem, in 2.0.6 function `getUrl()` in Yii don't have param `$additionalParams`, update version and all will be okay.

Comment: how can i update yii using composer

Comment: Change version in `composer.json` and run `composer update`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152767/discussion-between-mayank-vadiya-and-yupik).

Comment: @Yupik i have change version but still getting same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152827/discussion-between-mayank-vadiya-and-yupik).